# Como saber se todos os objetos de um array estão inseridos em outro array baseado em uma propriedade em comum nos dois arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo dois arrays de objetos e preciso verificar se todos os itens de um array estão contidos no outro array.

Preciso saber se o array2 está contido no array1 utilizando a propriedade `id` de cada item dos arrays.

Deve retornar `true` se todos os elementos de array2 estão presentes no array1 e `false` caso contrário.

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Badaró',
    altura: 1.75,
  },
  {
    id: 68,
    name: 'Badalão',
    altura: 1.65,
  },
  {
    id: 74,
    name: 'Badalador',
    altura: 1.55,
  },
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'Badaladinho',
    altura: 1.45,
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    id: 68,
    name: 'Badalão Choris',
    altura: 1.69,
  },
  {
    id: 74,
    name: 'Badalador Bang',
    altura: 1.59,
  },
];
```

Tentei utilizar `.every()` combinado com `.includes()` da seguinte maneira ([achei aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337/check-if-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)):

```
array1.every((v) => array2.includes(v))
```

Mas o resultado que obtive não foi o esperado, preciso verificar por ID, pois possivelmente os objetos de cada array podem conter outras propriedades diferentes.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar duas novas variáveis que irão armazenar a lista de id's dos 2 arrays, após isso, verificar se o array2 está inteiramente inserido no array1. Exemplo:

```
const idList = array1.map(item => item.id);

const idListCheck = array2.map(item => item.id);

const isEveryInList = idListCheck.every(id => idList.includes(id));
```

Uma dica seria nomear as variáveis de forma mais clara, no lugar de usar "array1" utilizar algo mais simples de entender, exemplos de variáveis

```
productList ou products
itemList ou items
...
```